# Режим раскрытия контекстного подменю

Tags: wpf

Контекстное подменю открывается влево. Как изменить такое поведение?

Xaml:

```
<Canvas>
  <Canvas.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
           <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
           <MenuItem Header="Close"/>
        </MenuItem>
     </ContextMenu>
   </Canvas.ContextMenu>
</Canvas>
```

[image: Gif]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это проблема не WPF, нужно изменить параметр реестра.

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> вводим `regedit` дальше переходим в директорию:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows

в параметрe MenuDropAlignment изменить значение на 0. Перезагрузить компьютер(или выйти из системы и войти)